# Excel formula for counting number of sales by month

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that has a list of sales for each salesman. Each salesman has his own tab and it is sorted by client name, date of sale, and amount of sale. I would like for my sheet to count the amount of sales per month of each month.

[image: Real column layout]

where:

```
      B                      C             D
Client's Name | Date (1/1/2014 format) | Price |
```

So I am using the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Nash!B:B, Nash!C:C, "<9/1/14", Nash!C:C, ">7/31/14")
```

This is giving me the following error:

> COUNTIFS expects all arguments after position 2 to be in pairs.

What I would like my sheet to tell me is:

```
June: 3
July: 9
August: 2
```

I am currently using this formula to calculate the value of all the sales per month for the salesman:

```
=SUMIFS(Nash!D:D, Nash!C:C, "<9/1/14",Nash!C:C, ">7/31/14")
```

This is not giving me any errors and works well.

What do I do to fix my formula?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `COUNTIFS()` Excel worksheet formula pertinent to you case, modified as shown below:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,">7/31/2014",C:C,"<9/1/2014"),
```

or with worksheet specified (e.g. `Nash!`)

```
=COUNTIFS(Nash!C:C,">7/31/2014",Nash!C:C,"<9/1/2014"),
```

The same result could be achieved with `COUNTIF()` (using AND operator for multiple criteria), or `SUMIFS()` as mentioned in your post. Using PivotTable will be the "overkill" for such simple task.

Regards,